# Disable and hide all keyboard shortcuts for one application

Tags: applications

I would like to disable and hide from the menu bar all shortcuts for one application.  Is there a way maybe to output all shortcuts for a specific application so I can mainly and them under System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->App Shortcuts.

I have been creating duplicate shortcuts and when there is a duplicate it just displays nothing(no shorcut).

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool application called [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) which can display all the shortcuts in any application on screen.